# What is the best way to make this API request in Swift?

Tags: swift, api, post

Sorry if this question is too repetitive here but I cant figured out how to made it :(

I need to send data to an API (https://www.opticutter.com/public/doc/api#introduction) my data comes from somes TextFields and this is what the API expect.

```
curl -H "Content-type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
-X POST -d '{
    "stocks" : [{
        "length" : "60",
        "width" : "40",
        "count": "10",
        "grainDirection": null
    },{
        "length" : "40",
        "width" : "35",
        "grainDirection": null
    }],
    "requirements" : [{
        "length" : "30", 
        "width" : "20", 
        "count": "8",
        "grainDirection": null
    },
    {
        "width" : "20", 
        "length" : "20", 
        "count": "3",
        "grainDirection": null
    }],
    "settings" : {
    "kerf": "0"
    }
}'
```

So I already have the code to make the request but I cant realize how convert the data into that.

Hope do you understand what I need.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about sharing the code you're using to make the request so we can see what is wrong with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach in my opinion is to map your data into structs/classes and use the [Decodable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/encodable) protocol.

```
struct Stock: Encodable {
    let length: Int
    let width: Int
    let count: Int
    let grainDirection: Int?
}

struct Requirement: Encodable {
    let length: Int
    let width: Int
    let count: Int
    let grainDirection: Int?
}

struct Setting: Encodable {
    let kerf: Int
}

struct MyObject: Encodable {
    let stocks: [Stock]
    let requirements: [Requirement]
    let settings: [Setting]
}
```

Then you build the `MyObject` with the data from the textfields:

```
let myObjectData = MyObject(stocks: [
                                Stock(length: 60, width: 40, count: 10, grainDirection: nil),
                                Stock(length: 40, width: 35, count: 0, grainDirection: nil)
                            ],
                            requirements: [
                                Requirement(length: 30, width: 20, count: 8, grainDirection: nil),
                                Requirement(length: 20, width: 20, count: 3, grainDirection: nil),
                            ],
                            settings: [Setting(kerf: 0)])
```

Finally on the request you would have to encode the data, converting it into a JSON String for example:

```
do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(myObjectData)
    let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)
    print(jsonString)
} catch {
    debugPrint(error)
}
```

This will produce a json string with the following result:

```
{
   "stocks":[
      {
         "width":40,
         "count":10,
         "length":60
      },
      {
         "width":35,
         "count":0,
         "length":40
      }
   ],
   "requirements":[
      {
         "width":20,
         "count":8,
         "length":30
      },
      {
         "width":20,
         "count":3,
         "length":20
      }
   ],
   "settings":[
      {
         "kerf":0
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: That's what I looking for! I couldn't understand how to convert my code into what the api expected. Now I'm trouble with the response, its give me an error "Method not supported" but for sure is something wrong in my API call. I'll try to figured out. Thanks a lot for your help!